# Set a TextField's location in a java applet

Tags: java, applet, textfield, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I am trying to add an extra feature to a school project.
When I add a TextField to the code it appears at the top in the middle. I want to be able to change the location of the `TextField`

**My code looks like:**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Prac4 extends Applet {
char ch;
char letter = 'X';
char other = '#';
char c1;
char c2;
char c3;
char c4;
char c5;
char c6;

String s1;
String s2;
String s3;
String s4;
String s5 = "How are you?";
String s6 = "What are we testing here?";
String s7 = "  How many spaces are in this text?   ";
String s8;
String s9;
String s10;
String s11;

TextField text1;

int num = 6;
int x;

boolean answer;

public void init() {
    ch = '%';

    s1 = new String();
    s2 = new String("Hello");
    s3 = new String(s2);
    s4 = "  Hello   ";

    text1 = new TextField(20);
    text1.setText("JOHN DOE");
    add(text1);
    text1.setBounds(10,10,50,50);
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.drawString(s2 + " What a nice day.", 25, 25);
    g.drawString("s2 equals " +s2, 25, 50);

    g.drawString("Length of s2 is " + s2.length() + " characters", 25, 75);

    g.drawString("s2 to UpperCase is " + s2.toUpperCase(), 25, 100);
    g.drawString("s2 to LowerCase is " + s2.toLowerCase(), 25, 125);

    s1 = s4.trim();
    g.drawString("The origional s4 is:" + s4, 25, 150);
    g.drawString("After trimmming s4 is:" + s1, 25, 175); 

    s1 = s2.replace('H', 'h');
    g.drawString("s2 after a replace is " + s1, 25, 200);
    ch = s4.charAt(num);

    s1 = s2.substring(1, 4);
    g.drawString("s1 = s2.substring(1,4) returns " + s1, 25, 225);

    s1 = s2.substring(2,2);
    g.drawString("s1 = s2.substring(2,2) returns " + s1, 25, 250);

    g.drawString("With the string s6 = \"" + s6 + "\"", 25, 275);

    answer = s6.startsWith("Whi");
    g.drawString("answer = s6.startsWith(\"Whi\") reurns " + answer, 25, 300);

    answer = s6.endsWith("?");
    g.drawString("answer = s6.endsWith(\"?\") returns " + answer, 25, 325);

    x = "Wooloomooloo".indexOf("loo", 8);
    g.drawString("x = \"Woolloomooloo\".indexOf(\"loo\", 8) returns " + x + " but", 25, 350);

    x = "Wooloomooloo".indexOf("loo", 12);
    g.drawString("x = \"Woolloomooloo\".indexOf(\"loo\", 12) returns " + x, 25, 375);
    g.drawString("which says the substring \"loo\" was not found after  position 12", 25, 400);

    /*
     * Turn s7 into upper case
     *      display the result
     * 
     * Trim s7
     *      display the result
     */

    g.drawString("s7 in uppercase = \"" + s7.toUpperCase() + "\"", 550, 25);
    g.drawString("s7 without leading or trailing spaces = \"" + s7.trim() + "\"", 550, 50);

    /*
     * Define s8 as "alk on the wild sid"
     * Define c1 as "W"
     * Define c2 as "E"
     * Display c1 then s8 then c2
     */

    s8 = "alk on the wild sid";
    c1 = 'W';
    c2 = 'E';
    g.drawString(c1 + s8 + c2, 550, 100);

    /*
     * Define s9 as TRAVIS WESLEY
     * change s9 to lower case
     * Split string at " " using s9.split(" "); into s10 and s11
     * Define c3 as s10.charAt(0);
     * Define c4 as s11.charAt(0);
     * Define c5 as c3 upper case
     * Define c6 as c4 uppercase
     * Display s11 with replaced letter the s10 with replaced letter
     * 
     * Error occurs when the fist letter is repeated in the word 
     */

    s9 = text1.getText();
    s9 = s9.toLowerCase();
    String[] parts = s9.split(" ");
    s10 = parts[0];
    s11 = parts[1];

    c3 = s10.charAt(0);
    String s12 = String.valueOf(c3);
    c4 = s11.charAt(0);
    String s13 = String.valueOf(c4);
    c5 = Character.toUpperCase(c3);
    String s14 = String.valueOf(c5);
    c6 = Character.toUpperCase(c4);
    String s15 = String.valueOf(c6);
    g.drawString(s11.replaceFirst(s13, s15) + ", " + s10.replaceFirst(s12, s14), 550, 150);
}

public boolean action(Event e, Object o) {
    repaint();
    return true;
}
}
```

`text1.setLocation(x, y);` doesn't work

Comment: Where do want it positioned?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use setbounds method like below for this if you do not want use any layouts.

```
    text1.setBounds(10,10,50,50);
    setlayout(null)
```

But this is not the correct way though.You have to use like below only.

```
    TextField text1 = new TextField(20);
    text1.setText("JOHN DOE");
    add(text1);
    text1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

### Note

Andrew Thompson notes:

> Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are *not* conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a ***robust GUI***, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.
>
> 1. [image]
> 2. [image]

Comment: This doesn't change where the TextField is located, it is still at the top in the middle.

Comment: put your full code.because you also have to set the layout to null if you don't want any layout.like **frame.setLayout(null);**

Comment: Its not letting me upload a past that is mostly code. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you said.i didn't get it.say it clearly...try setting the layout first...

Comment: Stack Overflow wont let me edit my post with all my code as the post can't contain mostly code.

Comment: @X-Eon Ooops!!! then add some contents(a bit more about your problem)  with it... **OR** maybe add it as an answer(not the way though)

Comment: add **setLayout(null);** at last in your init method and change the setbounds value to fix textfield where you wanted it.

Comment: What's wrong with you and you're going to down-vote me for no reason, besides the fact that someone down-voted you for legitimate reasons. I didn't even down vote you. You have a serious problem. Now I will though.

Comment: @peeskillet  k i am really sorry for that now i changed. you?

Comment: *"now i changed."*  Now I wish I could cancel that -1.  Could you make an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22628963/edit) (addition) to your answer with my comment (without the *last sentence*)?  Then I can take away 1 down-vote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Yeah now i got how to roll it back to any version.But i'm not rolling back this one anymore though. And Thanks for your suggestions AndrewThompson..

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of your `setBounds` it looks like you want it centered at the top.

1. Create your text field by using the constructor that defines the number of character columns

   ```
   new JTextField(20);
   ```
2. Set the layout of your applet to `FlowLayout`

   ```
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   ```
3. Just add the text field

   ```
   add(text);
   ```
4. Setting location and size with null layouts is not the way. Learn to use the different layout managers by looking at [Laying out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: *"Setting location and size with null layouts is not the way."*  +10 to that.  :)